# optimizing mysql query with find_in_set in it

Tags: mysql

This query is taking too long time to run... 412.2163 sec

We have tables with different properties and a profile holder may have one or more such ids (i.e., properties) as comma separated ids in a columns of tbl_starcast_profile and search is carried out on profile table and user table and on properties table using find_in_set

Please check the query ...let me know whether this query can be optimized further.

tbl_starcast_profile structure - sample

```
    column                                           type
profile_id                                            int(11)
user_id                                               int(11)
                     ..
language_ids                                          text
accents_ids                                           text
singing_style_ids                                     text
```

now, these language_ids, accent_ids columns are having values like "12,34,56" (these are ids of the respective tables)

tbl_starcast_users structure - sample

```
    column                                           type
user_id                                               int(11)
performer_types                                       varchar(150)
                     ..
favourite_user_ids                                    text
```

tbl_starcast_performer_types table - sample

```
performer_type_id   performer_type_name     performer_type_display_name     performer_type_description  date_added             date_modified    
1                          actor                   Actor                           actor                  2015-12-28 18:05:05    2016-03-21 21:41:05
2                          model                   Model                           model                  2015-12-28 18:05:05   2016-02-12 17:57:30
3                          vo_Artiste            Voice Over Artist           vo_Artiste             2015-12-28 18:05:15     2016-02-12 17:59:02
4                          comedian                Comedian                      comedian                 2015-12-28 18:05:15   2016-02-12 17:57:09
5                          presenter               Presenter                     presenter              2015-12-28 18:05:27     2016-02-12 17:58:54
6                          dancer_movement       Dancer                        dancer_movement        2015-12-28 18:06:13   2016-02-12 17:57:17
```

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT p. * , group_concat( DISTINCT l.skill_name ) AS languages, concat( u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name ) AS full_name, 
u.favourite_user_ids

FROM (SELECT * , group_concat( DISTINCT CONCAT( language_ids, ',', music_ids, ',', dance_ids, ',', performance_ids, ',', presenting_ids, ',', sports_ids, ',', vehicle_licences_ids, ',', other_skills_ids )
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS superset_skills FROM tbl_starcast_profile GROUP BY profile_id) p, 

tbl_starcast_users u, 
tbl_starcast_performer_types per, 
tbl_starcast_skills l, 
tbl_starcast_unique_characteristics uniq, 
tbl_starcast_awards awrd

WHERE u.profile_id = p.profile_id
AND p.user_id = u.user_id
AND (u.performer_types REGEXP '(^|,)(4)(,|$)'AND (find_in_set( per.performer_type_id, u.performer_types ) >0) )
AND (find_in_set( l.skill_id, concat( p.language_ids, p.music_ids, p.dance_ids, p.performance_ids, p.presenting_ids, p.sports_ids, p.vehicle_licences_ids, p.other_skills_ids ) ) >0 ) 

GROUP BY p.profile_id;
```

Comment: This is called normalization. And here is problem `12,34,56`. Non-atomic values in column.

Comment: The best way to optimizing this would be to make other tables so you won't have enum columns